# Why CONTAINS and LIKE are not working in SQL?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sql-like

I'm trying to extract keywords from the `SQL database` and `CONTAINS` and `LIKE` are not worrking.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
sql = df.to_sql('table1', con=engine,index=True)
q1 = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE features LIKE "Swimming" ').fetchall()
q2 = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONTAINS(features, "Swimming") ').fetchall()
```

I've tred both the ways but i'm not getting the answer. And i get this error **OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: CONTAINS [SQL: 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CONTAINS(features, "Swimming") '] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)**

Comment: Remove the double quotes surrounding "Swimming" and replace with 'Swimming'.

Comment: On replacing "" by '' its giving a syntax error. @MadisonCourto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use double quote around your SQL statement and single quotes inside that.

```
q1 = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE features LIKE '%Swimming%' ").fetchall()
```

You might want to change 'Swimming' to '%Swimming%' so that it can be matched to any value that has Swimming in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187830/discussion-between-astroluv-and-joshua-pierce).